# org.primefaces.event.CellEditEvent not recognized as a type

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I use JSF2.0 , primefaces 3.3  in my project ,  i try to use primefaces DataTable - Cell Editing , but in the tableBean there is a function called "onCellEdit" which supposed to edit the cell

```
public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) {  
        Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();  
        Object newValue = event.getNewValue();  

        if(newValue != null && !newValue.equals(oldValue)) {  
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Cell Changed", "Old: " + oldValue + ", New:" + newValue);  
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
        }
```

the problem that i faced here is that Java don't recognize  "CellEditEvent" type  and suggests me ti change this type to "org.primefaces.component.celleditor.CellEditor"
i tried to import org.primefaces.event.CellEditEvent but it tells me that "The import org.primefaces.event.CellEditEvent cannot be resolved"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was introduced in PrimeFaces 3.5. So, upgrading to at least PrimeFaces 3.5 should do it.

As evidence, the class is absent in [PrimeFaces 3.4 javadoc](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.4/org/primefaces/event/package-summary.html) and present in [PrimeFaces 3.5 javadoc](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.5/org/primefaces/event/CellEditEvent.html). You can also see it by extracting the 3.3, 3.4 and 3.5 JAR files yourself and check the presence/absence of the desired class.

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/primefaces/event/CellEditEvent
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_02]
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427) [rt.jar:1.6.0_02]
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791) [rt.jar:1.6.0_02]
 at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:65) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
 at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1]

Comment: As answered, it is only available since PrimeFaces 3.5. You need to upgrade to PrimeFaces 3.5 (and remove all older versions from the runtime classpath).

Comment: that's exactly what i did !! i upgrated to PrimeFaces 4 , removed the older version but i go t this erroe now :

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/primefaces/event/CellEditEvent
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_02]
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427) [rt.jar:1.6.0_02]
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791) [rt.jar:1.6.0_02]
 at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:65) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
 at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.

Comment: If you're still facing this exception, then it means that you didn't properly upgrade, or you didn't properly rebuild the app, or you didn't properly redeploy the app, or you didn't properly clean/restart the server, or that the webapp's runtime classpath is actually a mess.